# PostgreSQL create table with PK, NOT NULL, varchar

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, heroku

Trying to use a Postgres db from Heroku that is connected to git for a php app. When I commit, I am getting errors already in the sql syntax.
I am not sure if it is me, or if there is missing required libraries.
Either would help greatly.

Here is the error that is coming up:

```
PHP Warning:  pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NOT
: LINE 2: UserID NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY varchar(255),                
^ in /app/index.php on line 69
```

And the corresponding code:

```
$raterTable = pg_query($conn, 
"CREATE TABLE Rater (
UserID NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY varchar(255),
email varchar(255),
name varchar(255),
joindate DATE,
type varchar(255) CHECK (type IN ('blog', 'online', 'food critic')),
reputation int CHECK (reputation >= 1 AND reputation =< 5) DEFAULT 1
");
```

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake.
Its varchar(255) NOT NULL..

I had them in reversed order.
Maybe this will help somebody one day :)